# XMLHttpRequest is not set by using .setRequestHeader

Tags: jquery, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cors

I try to make a cross domain request. To be able to do it I have to set an http header.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api',
                beforeSend: function (request)
                {
                    request.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Basic ...==');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
```

***beforeSend*** method seems to be invoked but '**authorization**' header is not set. Could you please help me to figure this out?

**UPDATED:** here are the received CORS headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Credential: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

It looks like **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** is missing.

Comment: Are you sure that your API supports CORS? The symptoms you are describing here strongly suggest that it doesn't. Or at least it doesn't support setting the Authorization header. Make sure your API sends the proper CORS headers. Also look at the Google Chrome's console to see potential errors. That's where those kind of warnings will be emitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your API supports CORS and that `Authorization` is an allowed request header to be set. When you send an OPTIONS request to the endpoint your API should respond with the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

This allows the client to set the `X-Requested-With`, `Content-Type` and `Authorization` request headers when calling the API method and it allows `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS` verbs from any origin domain.

So in order to debug the problem start by sending an `OPTIONS` request to your API endpoint and observe the response HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you Darin for your answer! It looks like server doesn't set Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Comment: That's the problem. You cannot perform a cross domain AJAX request in this case.